# factor() command in R is for categorical variables with hierarchy level only?

Tags: r

I'm quite confused on when to use

> factor(educ)    or     factor(agegroup)

in R. Is it used for categorical ordered data? or can I just use to it a simple categorical data with no hierarchy?

I know this is so basic. I really need some clarification.

Comment: See `?factor`. You have the option of specifying whether the factors are ordered or not.

Comment: @mrdwab I've checked that already, but it's quite vague. there are four options:<blockquote> is.factor, is.ordered, as.factor </blockquote>. can you give me definitions of each option? I was trying to model cox ph. and I have seen an example which use that factor code in educ and agegroup. Can I also use it in religion category?

Comment: Not so much "vague" as "terse". As for your larger question, you can/should use factors (whether ordered or not) for any categorical variable you work with; education, age-group, and religion (with the first two possibly ordered and the third one probably not).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't really see a clear question here, so perhaps a simple example would suffice as an answer.

Imagine we have the following data.

```
set1 <- c("AA", "B", "BA", "CC", "CA", "AA", "BA", "CC", "CC")
```

We want to factor this data.

```
f.set1 <- factor(set1)
```

Let's look at the output. Note that R has just alphabetized the levels, but does not say that this implies hierarchy (see the "levels" line).

```
f.set1
# [1] AA B  BA CC CA AA BA CC CC
# Levels: AA B BA CA CC
is.ordered(f.set1)
# [1] FALSE
```

However, using `as.numeric` on the factored data might fool you into thinking it is hierarchical. Note that "5" comes before "4" in the output below, and note also the alphabetized output of `table(f.set1)` (which also happens if you simply did `table(set1)`.

```
as.numeric(f.set1)
# [1] 1 2 3 5 4 1 3 5 5
table(f.set1)
# f.set1
# AA  B BA CA CC 
#  2  1  2  1  3
```

Let's now compare this with what happens when we use the `ordered` argument along with the  `levels` argument. Using `levels` plus `ordered = TRUE` tells us that this categorical data is hierarchical, in the order specified by `levels` (not alphabetically or in the order that we've entered the data).

```
o.set1 <- factor(set1, 
                 levels = c("CA", "BA", "AA", "CC", "B"), 
                 ordered = TRUE)
```

Even viewing the output shows us hierarchy now.

```
o.set1
# [1] AA B  BA CC CA AA BA CC CC
# Levels: CA < BA < AA < CC < B
is.ordered(o.set1)
# [1] TRUE
```

As do the functions `as.numeric` and `table`.

```
as.numeric(o.set1)
# [1] 3 5 2 4 1 3 2 4 4
table(o.set1)
# o.set1
# CA BA AA CC  B 
#  1  2  2  3  1
```

So, to summarize, `factor()` by itself just creates essentially a non-hierarchical sorted factor of your categorical data; `factor()` with the `levels` and `ordered = TRUE` arguments create hierarchical categories.

Alternatively, use `ordered()` if you directly want to create ordered factors. The order of the categories still need to be specified:

```
ordered(set1, levels = c("CA", "BA", "AA", "CC", "B"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can flag a factor as ordered by creating it with `ordered(x)` or with `factor(x, ordered=TRUE)`. The "Details" section of `?factor` explains that:

> Ordered factors differ from factors only in their class, but
>   methods and the model-fitting functions treat the two classes
>   quite differently.

You can confirm the **first part** of that quote (that they differ only in their class) by comparing the attributes of these two objects:

```
f  <- factor(letters[3:1], levels=letters[3:1])
of <- ordered(letters[3:1], levels=letters[3:1])
attributes(f)
# $levels
# [1] "c" "b" "a"
# 
# $class
# [1] "factor"
attributes(of)
# $levels
# [1] "c" "b" "a"
# 
# $class
# [1] "ordered" "factor"
```

Various factor-handling R functions (the "methods and model-fitting functions" of the **second part** of that quote) will then use `is.ordered()` to test for the presence of that `"ordered"` class indicator, taking it as a directive to treat an ordered factor differently than an unordered one.  Here are a couple of examples:

```
## The print method for factors. (Type 'print.factor' to see the function's code)
print(f)
# [1] c b a
# Levels: c b a
print(of)
# [1] c b a
# Levels: c < b < a

## The contrasts function. (Type 'contrasts' to see the function's code.)
contrasts(of)
#                 .L         .Q
# [1,] -7.071068e-01  0.4082483
# [2,]  4.350720e-18 -0.8164966
# [3,]  7.071068e-01  0.4082483
contrasts(f)
#   b a
# c 0 0
# b 1 0
# a 0 1
```

Comment: Nice details included in this answer.

Comment: @mrdwab -- Thanks. I wouldn't have bothered answering if I had known you were busy expanding your comment so nicely.