# Mathematical operators in categorical variables

Tags: r, categories

In my dataframe I have a variable with the following categories: `A1`, `A2`,`A3`, . . . `B1`, `B2`,`B3`, . . . `Z1`, `Z2`, `Z3`.

Although the variable is not numeric, we can define a logical order between them according to the letter and the number (the order the categries were described above).

---

My question is:

**Can we use `<`, `=` and `>` operators with this type of variables?**

For example, if I want to select rows for which `var1`values are between `A1` and `G3`. Can we use something similar to `df[df$var1>="A1" & df$var1<="G3",]`?

I saw code like that in STATA and I wonder if it is possible to do something similar in R. Thanks in advance.

Comment: R has an ordered factor class that supports those operations. Should be described on the ?factor page. Look up a function named `mixedorder` for the purpose of creating the proper sort order.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can use ordered factors. From the [docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/factor.html):

> If argument `ordered` is `TRUE`, the factor levels are assumed to be ordered.

```r
fct_levels = c("Python", "Julia", "R")

df  <- data.frame(
    var1 = factor("R", levels = fct_levels, ordered = TRUE),
    var2 = factor("Python", levels = fct_levels, ordered = TRUE)
)

df
#   var1   var2
# 1    R Python

df$var1
# Levels: Python < Julia < R

with(df, var1 > var2) # TRUE
with(df, var2 > var1) # FALSE
```

Note that you can set `ordered = TRUE` without setting the `levels` argument in which case you'll get alphabetical order.

```r
factor(c("Python", "Julia", "R"), ordered = TRUE)
# [1] Python Julia  R     
# Levels: Julia < Python < R
```

Thankfully, R will not let you compare this to `df$var1`.

#### A note about modelling

Note the warning in the docs:

> Ordered factors differ from factors only in their class, but methods and the model-fitting functions treat the two classes quite differently.

Specifically, this relates to whether orthogonal polynomial or treatment contrasts are used. You can read more about that in [Difference between ordered and unordered factor variables in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26119295/difference-between-ordered-and-unordered-factor-variables-in-r).

Comment: Only one doubt: If I understood well, when you define `factor(c("Python", "Julia", "R"), ordered = TRUE)` it should appear `Levels: Phyton < Julia < R` instead of what you wrote, shouldn`t it?

Comment: No. Note that the first argument is a vector that can have 0 or more of each of the elements, that will define the length and individual values in the return value. However, `levels=` should be (in this case) length-3 with the explicit order, as in `factor(c("R", "R", "Julia", "R"), levels = c("Python", "Julia", "R"), ordered = TRUE)`, noting that `levels=` sets the order and all possible values (whether or not they are in `x=`), and `x`= can have zero or more of each possible level. Without `levels=`, the default is to sort the unique values.

Comment: (For specificity, looking at the [source for `factor`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/44bcdf9a09d41f74ef8cc7832f18c6662ae2f263/src/library/base/R/factor.R#L24), notice that if `missing(levels)`, it orders the unique values in `x`.)

Comment: @R18 just to add to the comment by r2evans, if you want to get into the definition of alphabetical order, see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77871879/12545041) by ThomasIsCoding (and my comments). Even if the desired order for your factor happens to be alphabetical order and it will not change, I'd strongly recommend explicitly setting the order anyway, to avoid potentially definitions of alphabetical order (or "lexicographic sort") on different systems.

Answer (score 4):

If you are working with `character` (for `factor`, please refer to the answer by [@SamR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77871773/12158757) and [@Rui Barradas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77871909/12158757)), of course you can, for example

```
> x <- paste0(rep(LETTERS, each = 3), 1:3)

> x[x >= "A1" & x <= "G3"]
 [1] "A1" "A2" "A3" "B1" "B2" "B3" "C1" "C2" "C3" "D1" "D2" "D3" "E1" "E2" "E3"
[16] "F1" "F2" "F3" "G1" "G2" "G3"
```

As a matter of fact, characters are comparable (when typing `?Comparison` in the console, you will see the details like below)

> Comparison of strings in character vectors is lexicographic within the
> strings using the collating sequence of the locale in use: see
> locales. The collating sequence of locales such as ‘⁠en_US⁠’ is
> normally different from ‘⁠C⁠’ (which should use ASCII) and can be
> surprising. Beware of making any assumptions about the collation
> order: e.g. in Estonian Z comes between S and T, and collation is not
> necessarily character-by-character – in Danish aa sorts as a single
> letter, after z. In Welsh ng may or may not be a single sorting unit:
> if it is it follows g. Some platforms may not respect the locale and
> always sort in numerical order of the bytes in an 8-bit locale, or in
> Unicode code-point order for a UTF-8 locale (and may not sort in the
> same order for the same language in different character sets).
> Collation of non-letters (spaces, punctuation signs, hyphens,
> fractions and so on) is even more problematic.
>
> Character strings can be compared with different marked encodings (see
> Encoding): they are translated to UTF-8 before comparison.

Comment: This works here but... do you think the potential ambiguity owing to different encodings is a feature or a drawback? For example, if I define `x  <- c("_", "a", "A", "S", "T", "Z")` then `Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", "C"); x[x>"_"]` outputs `"a"` whereas `Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", "C.UTF8"); x[x>"_"]` outputs `"a" "A" "S" "T" "Z"`. Personally, as I can't be certain that the locale will remain constant on my own machine, let alone what it might be on others, this concerns me!

Comment: @SamR yes, my solution is just to show the possibility for example, and that's why I give the help document description for reference :)

Comment: Yes I'm always in favour of quoting the docs! These docs in particular though are one of those cases where the help file is the door to rabbit hole that runs much deeper than R, into encodings (what is byte-by-bye sorting in multibyte encodings?) and OS-level stuff that I try very hard not to have to think about :)

Answer (score 3):

**Here are two base R examples with the question's data.**

## 1. Character strings

In the 1st example the column is not a real categorical variable though some functions, such as the modelling functions, will coerce it to factor.

```r
# create a test df
df <- data.frame(var1 = expand.grid(LETTERS, 1:3) |> 
                   apply(1L, paste, collapse = "") |>
                   sort())
# 'var1' is of class character
str(df)
#> 'data.frame':    78 obs. of  1 variable:
#>  $ var1: chr  "A1" "A2" "A3" "B1" ...
# the condition in the question works
# because the characters, hence character strings, 
# do have an order
df[df$var1 >= "A1" & df$var1 <= "G3", , drop = FALSE]
#>    var1
#> 1    A1
#> 2    A2
#> 3    A3
#> 4    B1
#> 5    B2
#> 6    B3
#> 7    C1
#> 8    C2
#> 9    C3
#> 10   D1
#> 11   D2
#> 12   D3
#> 13   E1
#> 14   E2
#> 15   E3
#> 16   F1
#> 17   F2
#> 18   F3
#> 19   G1
#> 20   G2
#> 21   G3
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## 2. Ordered factors

This is the best way to handle a categorical variable with an order.

```r
# coerce to ordered factor first
df$var1 <- ordered(df$var1)
# or, with the base R pipe operator
# df$var1 <- df$var1 |> ordered()

# the condition in the question works and
# this is a more natural way of processing
# categorical variables
df[df$var1 >= "A1" & df$var1 <= "G3", , drop = FALSE]
#>    var1
#> 1    A1
#> 2    A2
#> 3    A3
#> 4    B1
#> 5    B2
#> 6    B3
#> 7    C1
#> 8    C2
#> 9    C3
#> 10   D1
#> 11   D2
#> 12   D3
#> 13   E1
#> 14   E2
#> 15   E3
#> 16   F1
#> 17   F2
#> 18   F3
#> 19   G1
#> 20   G2
#> 21   G3
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>