# What are the practical differences between 'factor' and 'string' data types in R?

Tags: r

From other programming languages I am familiar with the string data type. In addition to this data type, R also has the factor data type. I am new to the R language, so I am trying to wrap my head around the intent behind this new data type.

**Question:** What are the practical differences between 'factor' and 'string' data types in R?

I get that (on a conceptual/philosophical level) the factor data type is supposed to encode the values of a categorical random variable, but I do not understand (on a practical level) why the string data type would be insufficient for this purpose.

Seemingly having duplicate data types which serve the same practical purpose would be [bad design](http://www.baddesigns.com/examples.html). However, if R were truly poorly designed on such a fundamental level, it would be much less likely to have achieved the level of popularity it has. So either a very improbable event has happened, or I am misunderstanding the practical significance/purpose of the factor data type.

**Attempt:** The one thing I could think of is the concept of "factor levels", whereby one can assign an ordering to factors (which one can't do for strings), which is helpful when describing "ordinal categorical variables", i.e. categorical variables with an order (e.g. "Low", "Medium", "High").

(Although even this wouldn't seem to make factors *strictly* necessary. Since the ordering is always linear, i.e. no true partial orders, on countable sets, we could always just accomplish the same with a map from some subset of the integers to the strings in question -- however in practice that would probably be a pain to implement over and over again, and a naive implementation would probably not be as efficient as the implementation of factors and factor levels built into R.)

However, not all categorical variables are ordinal, some are "nominal" (i.e. have no order). And yet "factors" and "factor levels" still seem to be used with these "nominal categorical variables". Why is this? I.e. what is the practical benefit to using factors instead of strings for such variables?

The only other information I could find on this subject is the following quote [here](http://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/modules/factor-variables/):

> Furthermore, storing string variables as factor variables is a more efficient use of memory.

What is the reason for this? Is this only true for "ordinal categorical variables", or is it also true for "nominal categorical variables"?

**Related but different questions:** These questions seem relevant, but don't specifically address the heart of my question -- namely, the difference between factors and strings, and why having such a difference is useful (from a programming perspective, not a statistical one).

[Difference between ordered and unordered factor variables in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26119295/difference-between-ordered-and-unordered-factor-variables-in-r)
[Factors ordered vs. levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23396591/factors-ordered-vs-levels)
[Is there an advantage to ordering a categorical variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21585056/is-there-an-advantage-to-ordering-a-categorical-variable)
[factor() command in R is for categorical variables with hierarchy level only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12978326/factor-command-in-r-is-for-categorical-variables-with-hierarchy-level-only)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Practical differences:

1. If x is a string it can take any value. If x is a factor it can only take a values from a list of all levels. That makes these variables more memory effecient as well.

example:

```
> x <- factor(c("cat1","cat1","cat2"),levels = c("cat1","cat2") )
> x
[1] cat1 cat1 cat2
Levels: cat1 cat2
> x[3] <- "cat3"
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, 3, value = "cat3") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
> x
[1] cat1 cat1 <NA>
Levels: cat1 cat2
```

2. As you said, you can have ordinal factors. Meaning that you can add extra information aout your variable that for instance level1 < level2 < level3. Characters don't have that. However, the order doesn't necessarily have to be linear, not sure where you found that.

Comment: Oh I just assumed that the order had to be linear, because that's how the elements of a vector are listed. So it is possible to make real partial orders/trees with the factors? I.e. "Mother > child" "father > child" but "mother" and "father" are incomparable (or two siblings are incomparable, since they aren't descendants/ancestors of each other)?

Comment: Just to clarify, by not linear I mean that cat2>cat1 and cat3>cat2 does NOT necessarily mean that the difference between cat3 and cat1 is  two times the difference between cat2 and cat1. The fact that R gives them the values 1,2 and 3 doesn't mean that the order is that linear in the same way as R gives the values 1,2 and 3 even if they weren't defined as ordered. It's just a dummy encoding.
That being said, I am not sure whether you can have one factor vector partially ordered as the one you've mentioned, I doubt it though, you'll probably have to go with 2 different ordered vectors

Comment: There is no longer any material difference in storage requirements for factor and character vectors. The character vectors are hashed, so duplicate map to the same result.